# MS Office updates are not downloading via Windows Update, only though Office Updates

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-office, windows-update, updates

OS: Windows 10 Pro x64 (1703), MS Office Pro Plus 2016 x64.

On my work PC, running the same OS/Office versions, I get Office updates through Windows Update.  However, on my personal PC, I have to go into File->Account->Update Options (in *e.g.* Word or Excel) in order to download updates for MS Office.  (They will eventually download on their own if I wait long enough, just not through WU.) Is there some setting I can change to get these to update when WU checks for updates?

Answer (score 1):

You can enable Microsoft Update on Windows 10 [with vbscript or the registry](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa826676%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396):

Create a vbs file with the following content, then run it:

```
Set ServiceManager = CreateObject("Microsoft.Update.ServiceManager")
ServiceManager.ClientApplicationID = "My App"

'add the Microsoft Update Service, GUID
Set NewUpdateService = ServiceManager.AddService2("7971f918-a847-4430-9279-4a52d1efe18d",7,"")
```

Or use the registry to fix it by adding the following values:

HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\WindowsUpdate\PendingServiceRegistration\7971f918-a847-4430-9279-4a52d1efe18d

ClientApplicationID = My App

RegisterWithAU = 1

Or use an elevated command prompt to fix it by running both of these commands:

```
reg add "HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\WindowsUpdate\PendingServiceRegistration\7971f918-a847-4430-9279-4a52d1efe18d" /v "ClientApplicationID" /t REG_SZ /d "My App"
reg add "HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\WindowsUpdate\PendingServiceRegistration\7971f918-a847-4430-9279-4a52d1efe18d" /v "RegisterWithAU" /t REG_DWORD /d 1
```

Comment: What is the `My App` value for MS Office?

Comment: To enable "Microsoft updates" (which includes Office and other non-Windows updates from MS) you need to use "My App". The exact code above should be used. There is not a separate key exclusive to Office-related updates that excludes other non-Windows updates.

Comment: Tried this; rebooted - doesn't do anything.

Comment: did you run the VBS or reg commands, and did you run them elevated?